# Giving row more "breathing room" in LaTeX tabular environment

Tags: tables, spacing

I'm creating a tabular environment in LaTeX, which has math mode entries within cells. One thing that bothers me a little is that the row size seems mostly calibrated to the main text, and so when I use subscripts and fractions, they end up bumping up against my \hline entries. An example is given below (zoomed in). As you can see, the j subscripts bump up against the below hline and the fraction bumps on both sides.

Is there any way to secularly increase the relative distance between rows/between hline and rows for my entire environment?

Thanks.

Example:

Code:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|}

\hline
Model & Paper & $u_{ijt}$ & $p_{it}$ \\
\hline
\multirow{2}*{Inattention} & \cite{HHSM} & $v_{it}(x_{jt})$ & $\text{Pr}\{\beta(x_{j^*t} - x_{j^*(t-1)}) \geq \eta\}$ \\
\hline
 & \cite{AA} & $v_{it}(x_{jt})$ &  $\dfrac{\exp(\beta x_{id})}{1+\exp(\beta x_{id})}$\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Output:

[image: Example]

Comment: You might want to use the `cellspace` package.

Comment: Note the math operator `\Pr` is already defined, so you don't have to use `\text`.